# How can I store road maps in postGIS?

Tags: postgresql, gis, openstreetmap, postgis

How do I export a OSM road map into a postGIS database?
Also if I have the the coordinates of the intersections can I get the section of the road that I need?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [osm2pgsql](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql) tool, which supports osm xml (*.osm).

Basic usage:

```
osm2pgsql -d your_geo_database your-osm-data.osm.bz2
```

This command imports the `your-osm-data.osm.bz2` file in the `your_geo_database` database.

The database must exist and must have the postgis extension loaded.

Yes, you can import only a part of you osm data by specifying the bounding box you want to import using the `--bbox` option and comma separated coordinates as minlon,minlat,maxlon,maxlat, i.e:

```
osm2pgsql -l -d your_geo_database --boxx -0.5,51.25,0.5,51.75 you-osm-data.osm.bz2
```

You can not specify the section of roads you need using a point, but you can construct a bounding box around this point, i.e. a square 100m X 100m

Type

```
osm2pgsql --help
```

to see all options.

Same important options are:

`-l` :      Store data in degrees of latitude & longitude (srid 4326)

`-a` :  Add the OSM file into the database without removing         existing data.

`-d -H -U -W -P`: database connection options: database name, host, username, password, port.

If your osm file is too big, you will probably need to use some options which optimize the memory usage, i.e.: `--cache-strategy`, `--slim` or `--unlogged`

Comment: The second part of my question wasn't clear, sorry. What I wanted to know was after storing it in a database, can I retrieve the data for a single road with database queries using the coordinates of each intersection?

Comment: @user3927312 that's a different question.

Comment: You're right it is. I'll create a new question and link it here.